# Drawing Image on Android

Tags: android, image, performance, android-imageview

I need to draw an image on android, but I want to draw it row by row how can I do that with good performance.

Also, if I need to draw a random region in an image how could i get it in android....

I'm totally new to the android programming.

Answer (score 1):

This is all explained in the [Canvas and Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) developer guide.

Basically the Canvas API "provides a set of 2D-drawing APIs that allow you to render your own custom graphics onto a canvas".

Comment: Right, but what about the performance, drawing on Canvas, is it really fast to produce an image rendering effects????

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

http://androidcodesnippetsblog.blogspot.in/2013/01/drawing-image-using-canvas-in-android.html

try this this will help you.